# Customize Sublime Text 3 bracket highlighter colors

Tags: css, plugins, sublimetext3

I'm using the Brackethighlighter plugin for ST3 and am looking for the setting that controls the outline colors used when matches are found. The white is a bit much and distracts me when I can't read the wrapped lines very well. It's worse when the wrap is closer together or the tags are very long (very common in Angular).

For example:

[image]

Not that bad here, but my question is, is it possible to change the white outline to either a darker non-black background color? Or, at least, change the white to a more subdued hue?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter#configuring-highlight-style) has all the info you need to customize colors of the plugin

Comment: Updating [above link](http://facelessuser.github.io/BracketHighlighter/customize/#configuring-highlight-style).

Answer (score 6):

Was able to finally figure it out with some User space preference updates and overrides:

https://gist.github.com/notbrain/058b263f145a1a0216c5

Add this to a new USER bh_core.sublime-settings:

```
{

  "bracket_styles": {

    "default": {
        "icon": "dot",
        // BH1's original default color for reference
        // "color": "entity.name.class",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.default",
        "style": "highlight"
    }

  }

}
```

And add this to whatever theme you're using (or modify as you see fit). This overrides the default, but you can also just override individual styles.

```
<!--appended to default to work with bh_core.sublime-settings brackethighlighter.default style-->
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>Bracket Tag</string>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>brackethighlighter.default</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>background</key>
    <string>#351501</string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#D4F20D</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

[image]

Comment: I am confused regarding this part "And add this to whatever theme you're using". Considering that i'm currently using the default sublime theme, then which file do I have to add this to. Iv'e made these changes to Widgets.stTheme, but i'm not sure if t's working.

Comment: @user258365 When you open up your Sublime preferences, what is the entry for "color_scheme": ? If I'm remembering correctly, that's the file you would edit.

Answer (score 0):

I not a web developer, but I use sublime text to code, and I wrote a small highlighter plugin for myself, the color and style of highlight is decided by scope and flags in "add_regions(key, [regions], , , )" which is a API from Sublime text.

I check the plugin you mentioned, if I found it correctly [Brackethighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter#customizing-brackethighlighter), it mentions that it has properties for setting color and style, you can check that out. In my experience, scope "comment" is usually a bit darker than the pure white one~

Hope it helps.

Comment: how do i Add this to a new USER bh_core.sublime-settings??